# using Find() method with async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, model-view-controller, async-await

I have sync method i MVC controller , which I want to make it async
it had this in the controller

```
  var user = _context.Users.Find(UserId);
  cart.User = user;
  _context.SaveChanges();
```

but when I change to await ,

```
  var user =await _context.Users.Find(UserId);
  cart.User = user;
  _context.SaveChanges();
```

it gives me error

> User doesnot contain definition for 'Getawaiter' and no accessible extension accepting a first argument of type User.......

but if I change it to

```
 var user = await _context.Users.Where(p=>p.Id==UserId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
 cart.User = user;
 _context.SaveChanges();
```

it works fine. Cann't I use find method with async/await???

Comment: Which Entity Framework version used?

Comment: P.S. You probably want to change `SaveChanges` to `SaveChangesAsync`, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just make any method async by putting `await` before it. There has to be an async version of the method.

EFCore: [DbSet.FindAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.find?view=efcore-6.0)

EF: [DbSet.FindAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.findasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Answer (score 2):

> it works fine. Cann't I use find method with async/await???

For the same reason you cannot use `.FirstOrDefault()` with `await` and decided to use `.FirstOrDefaultAsync();`.

The method you are looking for is called `.FindAsync()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I write it as a response but I can't comment yet. In your .NET version `FindAsync()` exists? Eventually you can use that.